# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, django

Currently working on a Django website and I'm having an issue importing a class and its attributes from my `models.py` module into my `views.py` module within my music app. From what I understand Django uses metaclasses to construct models, so the defined fields don't end up as attributes on the class. Is this the problem and if so how do I solve it?

Directory Structure:

```
music  
    migrations  
    templates  
         _init_
         admin.py   
         apps.py  
         models.py  
         tests.py  
         urls.py  
         views.py
```

The code inside `models.py` is:

```
from django.db import models
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

def __str__(self):
    return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist
```

The code inside `views.py` is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Album
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.object.all()
    template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    context = {'all albums': all_albums,}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def details(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2> Details for Album id: " + str(album_id) + "  </h2>")
```

**The Error:**

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

**Error Location:** 
 `from .models import Album`

Answer (score 6):

Your `__str__` method must be defined into `Album` class, otherwise self is undefined

Comment: Just indent it.

Comment: What is the 'it' you are referring to?

Comment: Indent `__str__`  definition with its return statement by one tab (or 4 spaces if you prefer)

Comment: Thank for the feedback. I tried re-running the code with the indent and the error remains. Any ideas?

Comment: Another question. Are all *.py files into templates directory? Because Django reserve `templates` dir for storing .html files that compose views in it. Try to move all .py files outside it and delete `__init__.py` file (because is not longer needed).